# req.locals vs. res.locals vs. res.data vs. req.data vs. app.locals in Express middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

There are some similar questions asked but my question is that if I want to  propagate intermediate results that I get along the different routing middleware, what is the best way to do that?

```
app.use(f1); app.use(f2); app.use(f3);

function f1(req,res,next) {
  //some database queries are executed and I get results, say x1
  res.locals.dbResults = {...};
  next();
}

function f2(req,res,next) {
  // more processing based upon req.locals.dbResults 
  res.locals.moreResults = {....};
  next();
}
// ...
```

I think that I can get the same propagation of data through the different middleware by using **req**.locals. Also, it appears that the request and response objects both have the locals properties initialized to an empty object at the start of the request.

Also, one can set res.mydata or req.mydata properties too?

In theory, app.locals can also be used for passing this data along through the different middleware as it will persist across middlewares but that would be contrary to the conventional use of app.locals. It is used more for application specific data. It will also be necessary to clear that data at the end of the request-response cycle so the same variables can be used for the next request.

**What is the optimal and standard way to propagate intermediate results through middleware?**

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111143/express4-whats-the-difference-between-app-locals-res-locals-and-req-app-local/35111195

Answer (score 220, accepted):

As you mentioned, both `req.locals`, `res.locals` or even your own defined key `res.userData` can be used. However, when using a view engine with Express, you can set intermediate data on `res.locals` in your middleware, and that data will be available in your view (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072333/difference-between-assigning-to-res-and-res-locals-in-node-js-express)). It is common practice to set intermediate data inside of middleware on `req.locals` to avoid overwriting view data in `res.locals`, though this is not officially documented.

> **res.locals**
>   An object that contains response local variables scoped to the request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered
>   during that request / response cycle (if any). Otherwise, this
>   property is identical to `app.locals`.
>
> This property is useful for exposing request-level information such as
>   the request path name, authenticated user, user settings, and so on.
>
> Source: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the documentation distinction which works in favor of res.locals. You confirmed my understanding that in theory all approaches are technically the same. Lets wait for more comments. Upvoted your answer... certainly useful.

Comment: Side note: `res.render()` take precedence over `res.locals`. So someone could _accidentally_ overwritten the variable like so ```res.locals = { name: 'Jake' } // later in code... res.render('user.template', { name: 'Tony' }, (err, html) => {}) // the 'name' variable is now 'Tony'```

Comment: Anyway, well planned, clean and modular middleware design should be the better and long term solution than just relying on a single object key

Comment: req.locals (at least in typescript) doesn't appear to exist any longer, So i'm wondering if its now advised to use res.locals and not use req.locals at all?

Comment: IMO, because API caller can manipulate req.locals from request call, so better put the intermediate result in res.locals

Comment: dont IMO, how @YosuaLijantoBinar can the caller modify req.local; it would render req.locals unsafe for route handler data passing.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't come across req.locals while reading the express documentation,I don't even think it exists.

What I would advice is that use res.locals for storing data that's going to be rendered in your views.

If you want to store custom data,create a property(preferably array or object) inside res or req instances eg req.data={},then store your data inside this "object".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).