# Express4. What's the difference between app.locals, res.locals and req.app.locals?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am so confused while using express 4. I use *express-generator* to generate my project. And there are **app.js** in root and **index.js** in router file. However, the tutorial on internet about express are using router directly in **app.js**. So when I want to set some variables in **index.js**(in router file), I use app.locals, but it doesn't work. But when I change to the other two, my ejs template works... I am very confused. Anybody can tell me the difference between them and how to use correctly, please?

```
<!-- language: index.js in router file -->

    var app = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();

    ....

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var _user = req.session.user;
    if (_user) {
      //does't work!!
      //app.locals.user=_user;
      //I am not sure about which usage is correct below
      //1.
      req.app.locals.user = _user;
      //2.
      // res.locals.user=_user;
    }
}

<!-- language: lang-ejs -->

    <% if (user) { %>
      <li><a class="navbar-link">Welcome <%= user.name %></a>
      </li>
      <span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
      <li><a href="/logout" class="navbar-link" id="logoutBtn">Logout</a>
      </li>
      <% } else { %>
        <li><a href="#" class="navbar-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signinModal">登录</a>
        </li>
        <span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
        <li><a href="#" class="navbar-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signupModal">注册</a>
        </li>
      <% } %>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

- The [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals) object is a JavaScript object, and its properties are local variables within the application.

  ```
  app.locals.title
  // => 'My App' 
  app.locals.email
  // => 'me@myapp.com'
  ```

  Once set, the value of `app.locals` properties persist throughout the life of the application
- In contrast with `res.locals` properties that are valid only for the lifetime of the request. When you handle the route where you have a `res` object, you won't have an app object there and vice-versa for `app.locals`.
- You can access local variables in templates rendered within the application. This is useful for providing helper functions to templates, as well as app-level data. Locals are available in middleware via `req.app.locals` (see [req.app](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.app))

  ```
  app.locals.title = 'My App';
  app.locals.strftime = require('strftime');
  app.locals.email = 'me@myapp.com';
  ```

One picture from `Node.js In Action` book as below, describe the difference of `app.local` and `res.local`

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot! I have a much better comprehension now

Comment: can u explain me the advantages of using app.locals ? I am abit confused heather I should use it or not

Answer (score 13):

From  [express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html).

Here in short.

**app.locals**

The `app.locals` object is a JavaScript object, and its properties are local variables within the application.

This means you can declare a variable in your `app.js` with `locals` and access it within that script or pass it to the `response object`.

**res.locals**

With this you can set or send variables to client side html/view and it is only available in that view/html.

e.g.

```
app.get('/view', function(req, res) {
  res.locals.user = req.user;
});
```

Here the `user` variable is available in your html page requesting the `view` route.

**req.app.locals**

Locals are available in middleware via `req.app.locals`;