# How to access app.locals in other modules in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

With my main server.js file, I exported my app variable:

```
//Assume there's other code in this file of course
    var app = express();
    app.locals.database = //here's my DB connection. This variable works perfectly within the server.js file!
    module.exports = app;
```

I imported it into another module:

```
var app = require('../server');
```

But I cannot access the app.locals variables? I set a few of them within my server.js (such as database connection info) but I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'database' of undefined
```

when trying to read:

```
app.locals.database
```

What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: In my other module app is {}, but when I check it within the originating module it has tons of info.

Comment: Looks like you're doing this correctly.  I'm guessing that there's an issue in the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: if you look at the docs it's mentioned `Local variables are available in middleware via req.app.locals`

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar thanks man, you can post as answer if you want to create detailed explanation and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per docs `Once set, the value of app.locals properties persist throughout the life of the application`.

In your case, as you've exported app, it's perfectly fine to access this at file level (not sure the right term), where you've imported as app.locals.database (remember `app` is an object).

But if you want to access elsewhere where you've not imported, express makes it available to all middleware via `req.app.locals`. The docs clearly mentions `Local variables are available in middleware via req.app.locals`

Also checkout this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111143/express4-whats-the-difference-between-app-locals-res-locals-and-req-app-local), it give you a nice insight on `app.locals` and `req.locals`

Comment: Thanks, req.app.locals worked for me!