# Express js fix user authentication collision

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, jwt

I am making an app from express js, it uses firebase admin for authentication and I am also using custom jwt for user recognition, and mongodb for database.

I don't know the right term but usually happens rarely for eg, User A is editing his account, but for some reason User B's account gets edited.

I have made user authentication middleware.

```js
import {
  Request,
  Response,
  NextFunction
} from "express";
import JSONRESPONSE from "../utils/JSONReponse";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken"
import {
  User
} from "../models/User";

export async function AuthMiddleware(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  const JSONResponse = new JSONRESPONSE(res);
  try {
    const session = req.cookies.session;
    if (!session) return JSONResponse.notAuthorized();
    const decoded = < any > jwt.decode(session);
    const uid = decoded.user_id
    if (!uid) return JSONResponse.notAuthorized();
    const user = await User.findOne({
      uid
    })
    if (!user) return JSONResponse.notAuthorized();
    req.app.locals.currentUser = user;
    req.app.locals.uid = uid;
    next()
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    JSONResponse.notAuthorized();
  }

}
```

Here is my main routes:

```js
app.use("/api/auth", AuthRoutes)
app.use("/api/user", AuthMiddleware, UserRoutes)
app.use("/api/date", AuthMiddleware, DateRoutes)
app.use("/api/chat", AuthMiddleware, ChatRoutes)
```

How do I fix this issue, I am not sure what is causing this rare issue.

**UPDATE:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35111195/14786214

after looking at this answer. I think the problem was of `req.app.locals`
since `app.locals` stores the variable throughout the lifecycle of app while `res.locals` stores only for the request lifecyle.

Comment: @Brettski is there any alternative way for it?

Comment: The docs are saying it's an instance of the app, which is what `req` is. Still digging around on this