# Can the req object be manipulated within a request

Tags: node.js, express

Can the `req` object be manipulated within a HTTP request? So is there any chance a request can set a value for `req.token`? I know that various object properties like `req.query`, `req.body` etc. can be freely changed from the outside, but can new properties like `req.token` be added or is this example code safe?

```
var auth = function (req, res, next) {
    if (isValid()) {
        req.token = getToken();
        return next();
    }
}

app.get('/foo', auth, function(req, res) {
    if (req.token) {
        // valid request
    } else {
        // invalid request
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this, although the recommended way is to use req.locals. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451053/req-locals-vs-res-locals-vs-res-data-vs-req-data-vs-app-locals-in-express-mi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [req.locals vs. res.locals vs. res.data vs. req.data vs. app.locals in Express middleware](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451053/req-locals-vs-res-locals-vs-res-data-vs-req-data-vs-app-locals-in-express-mi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's safe, provided you don't overwrite a property that a special meaning (a non-exhaustive list of those can be found [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.properties)).

It's a commonly used technique, and it's also shown in [the Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.param).