# Why does Passport use req.user when res.locals.user is standard?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451053/req-locals-vs-res-locals-vs-res-data-vs-req-data-vs-app-locals-in-express-mi), user data should live on `res.locals.user` but in Passport.js examples, this data is put on `req.user`.

Why did Passport.js not follow the `res.locals` convention?

Answer (score 0):

req.local is just a place where user email and password is store.You can store it any other variable name also.

Basically passport manage things, you can customize all these things as per your requirement.
People follow  this structure due to :
local :{name ,password}
google :{token,refresh},
fb..... and so on so its easy to search during login

Comment: Yes, but this does not answer the question.