# res.local to pass array through Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, middleware

I'm building an object-of-arrays via multiple data-base queries in a single router.get() with Express & Node.

To do this I need to: (1) query a collection, (2) append the results to an object, (3) pass the object through middleware using next(), (4) repeats quite a few times, (5) end with a nifty object that has multiple arrays attached.

Here's the pattern I'm using (just one example):

```
}, (req, res, next) => {    

    let { checkBoosters } = req;
    let boosterNo = [];
    let boosterMoGo = [];

    if(!checkBoosters.checkBoosters.length){
        return next()
    }

    //re-check boosters (from sentry)
    for(let i=0; i<checkBoosters.checkBoosters.length; i++){

        Phases.find({name: "Booster", team_oid: checkBoosters.checkBoosters[i]._id, weeks: {$gt: 0}}, (err, doc) => {
            
            if(!doc.length){
                boosterNo.push(doc[0])
            }

            if(doc.length){
                boosterMoGo.push(doc[0])
            }

            if(checkBoosters.checkBoosters.length == i+1){
                res.locals.boosterMoGo = { boosterMoGo }
                req.boosterNo = { boosterNo }
                return next()
            }
        })
    }

}, (req, res, next) => {
```

This basically works, but you may have already noticed my problem...

1. I can't decide if I should be using the "req" or the "res.locals" to store these arrays?
2. The object is getting "checkBoosters.checkBoosters" type object patterns. Can I avoid this?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When passing data between middleware the general consensus seems to be that `res.locals` is the preferred way of doing this, see also this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33451885/10353987).
2. As for your second question the main reason you get `checkBoosters.checkBoosters` type object patterns is because you assign using `req.checkBoosters = { checkBoosters }` while `req.checkBoosters = checkBoosters` would give you your desired result (without constructing a new object with the redundant property `checkBoosters`).

Comment: Thanks @etarhan - that perfectly answered my questions. I'm still curious about the trade-offs between res.locals & req. I had a senior dev teach me the req approach, so I was defaulting to that, but I agree that all of the SO answers I've seen use the res.locals approach. Cheers.