# How to return a JSON for 404

Tags: node.js, express

In `express`, the framework seems to have created rules to return `404` in `app.js`.

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
```

I understand that `app.use` is a middleware, I still have few doubts. Am I correct about the following:?

1. In above code, `createError` creates a `HttpError`. The error is available in `err` variable in the next `use` call
2. What is the purpose of `res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};`. Why not send `err` for both dev and prod?
3. I want to send a `json` response for `404`. Do I change `res.render` to `res.send({message:"404 error"}`?
4. Where/how do I send body type to `JSON` in response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before repliyng to your question, I see you are using the boilerplate generated by `express-generator`. Keep in mind that it uses view rendering engines (that are not needed for JSON APIs). Also, you can (should!) modify the generated code for your needs, expecially when is about error handling.

1. Yes
2. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451053/req-locals-vs-res-locals-vs-res-data-vs-req-data-vs-app-locals-in-express-mi) you can read more about the `res.locals` property. It's not mandatory to use it, expecially if you are not using a view rendering engine with express. In the boilerplate, they decided to hide internal errors/variable values to views in a production env (and it makes sense).
3. `res.json({message:"404 error"}`
4. When you use `res.json()` you are repliyng with JSON data and you are also setting the `content type` for the response body to `application/json`, all with a single line. If you need more control, you can use `res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json')` just before calling `res.send()`

My advice: feel free to customize the error handling in your service. You can modify the logic of your last middleware (the error catcher) by deciding when and what to log, and the response data and format. The `res.locals` line can be safely deleted. Also, the `createError()` function can be replaced with your own logic. For example, I like to throw custom error from my controllers/services, then in the last middleware you can just reply to the user with a proper HTTP status code (500,501,502,400,401,403,404, etc).